# css transition after jquery addclass

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-transitions

Im trying to slowly expand a div after i add the active class with jquery but i cannot get it to work properly. 
The div just gets the width but the transition doesnt occur. 
I have tried doing an animation with jquery also but that didnt work either.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.Sliders').click(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
#SliderHolder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.Sliders {
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.active {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Wrapper">
  <div id="SliderHolder">
    <div id="Slide1" class="Sliders active"></div>
    <div id="Slide2" class="Sliders"></div>
    <div id="Slide3" class="Sliders"></div>
    <div id="Slide4" class="Sliders"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is due to your use of `display: table-cell` you cannot easily amend with cell widths, and certainly not with animation. Is there a specific reason you've used that rule?

Comment: Thats the easiest way i could think of when i wanted 1 div 100% and the others 50 px. Do you know a better way of doing this? The thing works, just not with the animation

Comment: So you want one div to fill the whole screen and the others to be aligned 50px incrementally off the screen?

Comment: No, it works as intended with the sizes at the moment. The divs thats not active fills 50px each and the active one fills the rest of the space.

Comment: I also tried with 

.active
{
    width:calc(100% - 150px);
}

.Sliders
{
    display:inline-block;
}

And they all fit on 1 row but the animation still does not occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add `width : 0%;` to `.Sliders` style and add transition to `.active` class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.Sliders').click(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
#SliderHolder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.Sliders {
  width : 0%;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.active {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Wrapper">
  <div id="SliderHolder">
    <div id="Slide1" class="Sliders active">1</div>
    <div id="Slide2" class="Sliders">2</div>
    <div id="Slide3" class="Sliders">3</div>
    <div id="Slide4" class="Sliders">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```